# Delphi XE2 FireMonkey Xcode installation problem

Tags: xcode, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have Delphi XE2 installed on my Win XP Pro system and Xcode installed on my 4 week old MacBook (my total Mac experience = 4 weeks).  Installed paserver, exported an iOS project to Xcode, loaded it up in Xcode (can see the project and the Pascal source etc.) and pressed run..

Build failed message.  Detail is-

Shell Script Invocation error
/users/rob/Library....  line 4
/usr/local/lib/fpc/2.5.1/ppcross386: No such file or directory

Is the Pascal compiler not there for some reason?  Or something else missing?
Does paserver paly a part in setting this stuff up on the Mac?
Could the problem be related to paserver not having full access to my Win system at the time it was installed?

I am struggling with this and my unfamiliarity with Mac (Lion) is not helping...

Rob

Comment: For making Mac OSX apps, you only need the paserver to run. Everything else is done on the PC. For iOS apps, you need XCode etc. You should be clear as to which you are wanting to do. Then just look at the help steps that describe what you need to do, as it all worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I actually created a screencast / video showing you the steps you need to take to configure everything. I think you forgot to install the FreePascal and FireMonkey tools on the Mac side.

Feel free to have a look at this [article](http://www.devia.be/news/article/setting-up-delphi-xe2-and-your-mac-to-run-and-debug-cross-platform-applicat/) .

There you should find all the info you need and you should be able to follow the Screencast to complete your setup

Comment: Thank you ... I might be creating more Delphi related screencast in the future ... so if there is a topic you are interested in ... feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Resolution!

Finally found the missing information -

Setup on Mac
One-time setup must be performed on the development Mac, in addition to the standard Xcode installation. The FireMonkey-iOS.dmg disk image file is usually installed with RAD Studio under the FireMonkey-iOS directory; this file must then be transferred to the Mac. Open it and run the two installer packages:

fpc-2.4.4.intel-macosx.pkg installs Free Pascal 2.4.4 under /usr/local/. 
FireMonkey-iOS-XE2.pkg. 
copies Free Pascal 2.5.1 source to /Developer/Embarcadero/fpc/. 
copies FMI source required for apps to /Developer/Embarcadero/fmi/. 
builds and installs Free Pascal 2.5.1 under /usr/local/. 
generates, builds, and installs required iOS SDK headers under /Developer/Embarcadero/fpc/.

All working now.

Nice video Steffan - very professional.  However my problem was with iOS specifically so did not help a lot, however I picked up a couple of tips.  Looking forward to the iOS video one referred to in the OSX video.

Thanks

Comment: Since you answered your own question you should go ahead and mark your answer as the "accepted" one. Click the empty tick next to your answer and it will become the accepted solution to this question.

Comment: FYI ... I created the iOS version of the previous video and corresponding post titled : "Configuring Delphi XE2 and your mac to develop, test and deploy iOS apps' ... you can find it here : http://bit.ly/qD1iUv     If you have some time ... could you check if it would have helped you solve your problem ?